# React Native Expo Navigation Not Working On App Start

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I Am Currently Building A Simple React Native Expo Project, And On the Expo Go App it works perfectly, but when I run my build, It's Not Auto Navigating.

The Goal is to load the app, as my home page I have simple text field that says "THE App Is Loading" as well as a function that checks if a user is logged in, if they are, send them to the home page, if they are not, send them to the log in page. and on expo go dev server it works perfectly, but when exporting the project to an apk, and installing it on my phone, when i open the app it stays on the "App is loading page" and does not navigate to either the log in, or the home page. here is my code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet, 
  Text, 
  View, 
  ImageBackground, 
  Image, 
  TouchableOpacity, 
  Button, 
  Alert, 
  TextInput, 
  ScrollView, 
  FlatList, 
  NativeModules,
  Dimensions,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  const Home = "Homepage";
  const chatname= "Chat";
  const Profile2Name = "My Profile";
  var ids = '';
  var user = '';
  var pfp = '';
  const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')



function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={Start} options={{ headerShown: false }} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={Landing} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Homenav} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        
        
        <Stack.Screen name="Sign Up!" component={SignUp} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Change Profile Picture" component={Changepfp} options={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Change Profile Bio" component={Changebio} options={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Log In!" component={LogIn} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} options={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} options={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Comments" component={Comments} />

        <Stack.Screen name="Message" component={Message} options={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }}/>

      

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;

function Start({ navigation }) {
  loada();
    const startapi = async (user) => {
      
      let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync
      (user);
      
      let value = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("user");
      global.user = (value);
    
      let valueb = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("ids");
      global.id = (valueb);
    
      let valuec = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("pfp");
      global.pfp = (valuec);
      if (result){
          navigation.navigate('Home')

      }else{
        navigation.navigate('Landing')
      }
    }
    ssi=()=>{
      setTimeout(() => {
        startapi("user");
      }, 2000);
      
    }
    ssi();

    return(
      <View>
        <Text>HI, The App Is Loading!</Text>
      </View>
    )


}


async function loada() {

    let value = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("user");
    global.user = (value);
    let valueb = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("ids");
    global.id = (valueb);
    let valuec = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("pfp");
    global.pfp = (valuec);


  
}
```

i'm not sure what is going on, but it baffles me that it works on the dev with no errors but does absolutely nothing on the actual build. i tried running  expo start --no-dev --minify but got no errors there either and had no issues with initial navigation. initially i did not have a timer on the startapi function, but added one thinking maybe it was running the function prematurely but the timer had no effect on the app. any help or advice would be appriciated!

UPDATE:
I added alerts within the code to try and debug it, but none of them are firing